# Sending message from content script to background script breaks chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to send a message from a content script to the background script in a chrome extension that triggers a rich notification to open. I can already achieve this but it breaks the rest of my extension.

In my content script I have a call to chrome.extension.sendMessage inside of which I load my extension code. This was all working fine until I added my notification code, I decided to use chrome Rich Notifications API as I would like to have buttons in my notification eventually, and I am led to believe that only the background script can open the rich notification, hence the need for messages. If I comment out the chrome.runtime.OnMessage.addListener function in background.js my extension logic loads properly again, so something about that call is conflicting with the chrome.extension.sendMessage function in inject.js.

Can anyone explain why this happens and how to fix it?

A simplified version of my code is as follows:

**manifest.json**

```json
{
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Test",
  "permissions": [
    "notifications"
  ],
  "background": {
    "persistent": false,
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "mywebsite/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "inject.js",
      ]
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "notificationIcon.png"
  ]
}
```

**background.js**

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender) {
    if (request.type == "notification")
      chrome.notifications.create('notification', request.options, function() { });
});
```

**inject.js**

```js
chrome.extension.sendMessage({}, function(response) {
    //code to initialize my extension
});

//code to send message to open notification. This will eventually move into my extension logic
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type: "notification", options: { 
    type: "basic", 
    iconUrl: chrome.extension.getURL("icon128.png"),
    title: "Test",
    message: "Test"
}});
```

Comment: Your first `sendMessage` does not have a type field, I'd guess that is something your listener is going to break on ("cannot read property 'type' of undefined").

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I updated the sendMessage to use {type: "initialise"} but my extension logic still fails to run.

Comment: What error are you getting in the console?

Comment: Ok, finally figured out how to see the console for the background.js . There is no error, I added a console.log(response) in my listener in background.js and I can see both my "initialise" and "notification" messages coming through. Do I need to return something in particular for my load message to work on the content script?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The problem was caused because my listener in background.js was not returning a response. So the function response of my chrome.extension.sendMessage was never being executed.

I changed my background.js to be:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.type == "worktimer-notification")
      chrome.notifications.create('worktimer-notification', request.options, function() { });

    sendResponse();
});
```