# Having issue with click event in chrome extension manifest version 3

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

I have made an extension to get a screenshot of the webpage and save it.
To use this extension, first, we have to click on our pinned extension, there will appear two buttons, i.e start and stop when we click on the start button, and then I have configured a keyboard shortcut to get screenshots, and saved them in our computer successfully,
Now I want to add a mouse click event that when the extension is started, and instead of a keyboard shortcut, I have to make a click event, that when the click clicked anywhere in the webpage, the screenshot will be taken, I am having an issue with the click event.
Other things are working fine. My code to make a click event, in **background.js**

```js
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(() => {
    console.log("clicked");
});
```

I am using manifest version 3. When I test this code, no error comes, and the click event does not call.
Please help

Comment: If the action has a pop-up, this event won't fire [here is the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/action/#event-onClicked)

Comment: Yes you are right, this is not fire, but I want this behavior to call, how can I do this, read a lot of documentation but did not get the solution

Comment: If you have a pop-up set. You can simply do something when the pop-up is opened (that means the extension's icon was clicked). When a pop-up's JavaScript is executed, it means the extension's icon was clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
chrome.action.setPopup({ popup: "" });
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(() => console.log("click here"));
```

**EDIT:**

Capture the click event on the webpage using `content.js` file. Then send a message to `background.js` after capturing the click event. In `background.js` receive the message and and do what you want to do.

> content.js

```js
document.addEventListener("click", () => {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    type: "click_event"
  });
})
```

> background.js

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.type == "click_event") {
      console.log("click event captured in current webpage");
      // Call the callback passed to chrome.action.onClicked
    }
});
```

You can follow this question: [Sending message from content script to background script breaks chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26156978/sending-message-from-content-script-to-background-script-breaks-chrome-extension)

Comment: By adding this, when I clicked on my extension pop-up, then this event will be called, I want to call this event when a user clicks anywhere on the webpage.

Comment: Capture the click event on the webpage using `content.js` file. Then send a message to `background.js` after capturing the click event. In `background.js` receive the message and and do what you want to do.

Comment: `I want to call this event when a user clicks anywhere on the webpage` -- You can call the callback passed to `chrome.action.onClicked`,  in `chrome.runtime.onMessage` to get this behavior.